# Echoing a table in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I want to have this table in PHP? how can I create this and use it in Javascript after?

```
echo "<table border='1'>
      <tr>
     <th>word</th>
     <th>meaning</th>
     <th>checking</th>
      </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['word'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>";
     echo "<div";
            echo "class='hiding' style='display:none'>" . $row['meaning'];
     echo "</div>";
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td>";
      echo "<input name=\"f\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\"> ";
  echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I want to use columns that have class=hiding attribute. but in this way it doesn't work and I have an error:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(...).item(0) is null
document.getElementById('hiding').style.visiblility = 'visible';
```

I think I should echo table another way but I don't know how?
Here is my Javascript code:

```
 document.getElementsByClassName.item(0).('hiding').style.visiblility = 'visible';
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('hiding')[0]` will get you the first element with class "hiding" after it has been created. To make sure that it has been created, use the onload event handler of the body

Comment: thanks alot, how can I get all items?

Comment: With a loop going from 0 to `document.getElementsByClassName('hiding').length-1`

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `getElementById` to get an element by its classname.

Try something like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hiding')[0].style.visibility = 'visible'
```

Answer (score 0):

change style.visiblility to style.display, and style.display = 'block' for shown

Comment: thanks a lot, I try it and it works correctly, but how can I get all elements instead of item(0)?

Comment: var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('hiding'); for(var i=0; i<elements.length, i++){ elements[i].style.display='block'; }